# Problema con validacion ajax php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, excel

Buenas tengo el siguiente código que recibe los parámetros de un formulario a través de ajax, el cual me funciona correctamente  mediante post sin ajax, pero al hacerlo por ajax me sale las validaciones incorrectas. Este es el php donde recibo los datos y mas abajo le dejo el ajax el formulario es recibe un text area y un input file que es un archivo excel que se subira a una carpeta y el nombre se guarda en la bd

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
header('Content-type: application/json');
$resultado = array();
// Traspaso de parametros desde la interfaz
$novedadLaboratorioQuimico = $_POST['novedadLaboratorioQuimico'];

$directorio = "../excel/"; //ruta actual
deleteDirectory($directorio);
$archivo = $_FILES["archivoExcel"]['name'];
$fecha_actual= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$random= strtotime($fecha_actual);




// Crea arreglos de valores entregados por $_POST y nombre de estos.
$arregloValorDato = array($novedadLaboratorioQuimico,$random.$archivo);
$arregloNombreDato = array('Novedades Laboratorio químico','Excel');
$verificar_dato = "SELECT * FROM dato WHERE id_areaDato = 4";
$query_verificar = $con->query($verificar_dato);
if ($query_verificar->num_rows <= 0) {
    // Inserción de valores nuevo usuario.
    ;   
     $destino ="../excel/".$random.$archivo;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivoExcel']['tmp_name'],$destino);
    $cadena = "INSERT INTO dato (valor_dato,nombre_dato,id_areaDato) VALUES";
    // Ciclo for que recorre los arreglos y los inserta en la base de datos
    for($i=0; $i<count($arregloValorDato); $i++){
        $cadena.="('".$arregloValorDato[$i]."','".$arregloNombreDato[$i]."','4'),";
    }
    // Elimina el último valor de los aareglos
    $cadena_final = substr($cadena, 0, -1);
    // Asigna ; al final del INSERT INTO
    $cadena_final.=";";
    // Genera la consulta a la base de datos
    $query = $con->query($cadena_final);
    if($query!=null){
        $resultado = array("estado" => "true");
        return print(json_encode($resultado));
    }else{
        $resultado = array("estado" => "false");
        return print(json_encode($resultado));
    }
}
else{
    $resultado = array("estado" => "false");
    return print(json_encode($resultado));
}   

    function deleteDirectory($dir) {
    if(!$dh = @opendir($dir)) return;
    while (false !== ($current = readdir($dh))) {
        if($current != '.' && $current != '..') {
      //      echo 'Se ha borrado el archivo '.$dir.'/'.$current.'<br/>';
            if (!@unlink($dir.'/'.$current)) 
                deleteDirectory($dir.'/'.$current);
        }       
    }
    closedir($dh);
    //echo 'Se ha borrado el directorio '.$dir.'<br/>';
    @rmdir($dir);
}
```

?>

```
$("#AgregarDatoLaboratorioQuimicoForm").bind("submit", function(){
$.ajax({
type: $(this).attr("method"),
url: $(this).attr("action"),
data: $(this).serialize(),
success: function(response) {
  if (response.estado == "true"){
    $("body").overhang({
      type: "success",
      message: "¡Datos ingresados correctamente!",
      duration: 3,
    });document.getElementById("AgregarDatoLaboratorioQuimicoForm").reset();
  }else{
    $("body").overhang({
      type: "error",
      message: "¡Error al ingresar datos!"
    });
  }
},
error: function(){
  $("body").overhang({
    type: "error",
    message: "¡Error en el proceso ingresar datos!"
  });
}
```

});
  return false;
});

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                                   <div class="panel-heading">
                                      <h4 class="panel-title">
                                         <a class="accordion-toggle accordion-toggle-styled collapsed" data-parent="#accordion3" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse_3_8">
                                         Laboratorio químico
                                         </a>
                                      </h4>
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse_3_8">
                                      <form id="AgregarDatoLaboratorioQuimicoForm" class="form-horizontal" action="../../php/agregarDatoLaboratorioQuimico.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                                         <div class="form-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                               <label class="control-label col-md-3">Novedades sobre muestras</label>
                                               <div class="col-md-4">
                                                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="novedadLaboratorioQuimico" id="novedadLaboratorioQuimico" ></textarea>
                                                  <span class="help-block"> Escriba un comentario explicando alguna novedad sobre alguna muestra especial.</span>
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                               <label class="control-label col-md-3">
                                               Subir archivo excel
                                               <span class="required">
                                               </span>
                                               </label>
                                               <div class="form-group">
                                                  <label>

                                                  <input type="file" name="archivoExcel" name="archivoExcel" id="archivoExcel">
                                                  </label>
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="form-actions">
                                            <div class="row">
                                               <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                                  <button type="submit" id="agregar_laboratorio" class="btn green">Agregar datos</button>
                                                  <button type="button" class="btn default">Cancelar</button>
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                      </form>
                                   </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar qué quieres decir con *me sale las validaciones incorrectas*?  ¿Podrías colocar también el HTML donde se encuentra el formulario que estás enviando (puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/228396/edit) para ello)? Gracias.

Comment: Por ejemplo sin el el ajax me hace todo el proceso correcto, pero al agregarle el ajax me tira el mensaje de error, y nose porque siendo que al hacerlo por el post con el form asi clasico funciona bien

Comment: ¿Podrías en una primera instancia comprobar simplemente que el archivo PHP está recibiendo bien los datos del formulario, retornando simplemente esto y mostrándolo en la consola de Javascript: `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: si los recibe bien pues al hacerlo sin ajax, me inserta los datos en la bd y me sube el archivo a la carpeta

Comment: No me refiero a *sin Ajax*. Me refiero al código actual con Ajax. He visto un error al menos en el código, el id del formulario en el HTML es el siguiente: `AgregarDatoLaboratorioQuimicoFormi`, pero en Ajax omites la `i`  final, por lo cual no te estará funcionando así, ahí falta la `i` final: `$("#AgregarDatoLaboratorioQuimicoForm").bind("submit", function(){`  y también aquí: `document.getElementById("AgregarDatoLaboratorioQuimicoForm").reset()` Corrige eso, y si sigue sin funcionar, como te digo, haz una prueba de los datos que se están pasando en el POST. Puede que haya otros errores.

Comment: a si perdon que le puse esa i para que no funcionara el ajax, era para ir probando, pero ya corregi el problema tenia que agregarle estas lineas al ajax  contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    data: new FormData(this),

Comment: Yes, yes... [es justo como dices](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158711/29967). Me alegro de que lo hayas solucionado.

Answer (score 0):

Veo cosas muy raras compañero. yo uso la libria parsley, pero para otro tipo de validacion te sirve el siguiente codigo. Antes de hacer el envio por ajax, valida en cliente. si todo a ido bien tendras que validad en servidor tambien en el PHP.

```html
 $("#contact_submit").on("click", function(e){

  var valido = true;
  valido&= $("#name").parsley().isValid();

  if (valido){
   e.preventDefault();
   var packetData = new FormData();
   
   packetData.append("name", $("#contactForm #name").val());

   $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "./save",
    contentType: false,
    data: packetData,
    processData: false,
    cache: false
   }).done(function( info ){
    var json_info = JSON.parse(info);
     })
   }
   
 });
```