# Enviar file mediante Ajax utilizando FormData

Tags: jquery

Estoy enviando informacion via ajax utilizando `FormData()` de jquery el problema es que tambien van archivos adjuntos, datos que van por texto:

```
let notas = $("textarea[name='Comunicacion_notas']").val()
let status = $("select[name='Comunicacion_estatus'] option:selected").val()
let comentario_archivo =    $("textarea[name='Comunicacion_comentario_archivo']").val()
```

intente utilizar:

```
<input  type="file" class="mt-1 form-control-file" name="Comunicacion_comentario_archivo_file">
```

`let file = $("input[name='Comunicacion_comentario_archivo_file']").prop('files')`

pero no se si sea la manera correcta para traer la informacion de input.

```
formData.append('archivo', file)
```

¿Alguien sabe como debe ir? incluir en el `formData` el valor de imagen o archivo seleccionado.

Comment: Tienes que cumplir algunos requisitos en tu petición Ajax, creo haberlos enumerado y explicado [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158711/29967), otra cosa muy importante es que en tu formulario debes indicar que el mismo es del tipo `enctype='multipart/form-data'`. El código muestra también cómo leer los datos enviados en el servidor (código PHP  al final de la respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas saber cuando tu INPUT cambie de contenido, de esta forma el mismo evento te proporcionará el file que necesitas mandar.

```
const formData = new FormData ();
$('[type="file"]').on('change', ev => {
  // Te regresa un arreglo con todos los archivos seleccionados...
  // Tomamos solamente el primero.
  formData.append('filename', this.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: Cannot read property '0' of undefined